# What is the syntax for binding a function to a toggle button?

Tags: rx-cocoa

The following is a snippet of tutorial code that binds a toggle switch to an activity indicator:

```
 aSwitch.rx.value
    .map { !$0 }
    .bind(to: activityIndicator.rx.isHidden)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

 aSwitch.rx.value.asDriver()
    .drive(activityIndicator.rx.isAnimating)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

What is the syntax of binding to a **private func()**?  
I want to be able to several things beyond merely flipping a boolean value.

Specifically, I would like to:

1. Toggle the title of another button;
2. Enable & clear a UITextView; and
3. Change a UILabel text.

Or is it better in this case, to merely use the familiar toggle-button @IBAction paradigm?

Answer (score 0):

If the title of another button is dependent on the value of your `UISwitch`, then you should do something like:

`let buttonText = aSwitch.rx.value.map { $0 ? "Button is on" : "Button is off" }`

and then `bind` (or `drive`, if you're using `Driver`) your `button.rx.title` to the this Observable. A similar approach is needed for things like clearing a `UITextView` or changing the text on a label.

If your UIView elements depend on more than just the state of your toggle, then a more complex structure is needed than simply using `map`, e.g. by using `withLatestFrom`, `combineLatest` or other operators (see: http://www.rxmarbles.com). Since this introduces a bunch of new complexity, is it common to contain this logic in a so-called ViewModel. There are plenty of articles detailing how a so-called `MVVM` pattern works with rxSwift.